# iPhone Popup Changes on Device Rotation

Tags: ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I am working on an app with a popover that displays a `UIDatePicker`.  I have it set up to always be a popup view, even on phones.  It works until I rotate the device to landscape.  When I do this, the popover displays the way a popover would normally display on an iPhone that is in landscape mode.

This is what it looks like in portrait mode.  It's exactly what I wanted it to look like.

[image]

And here it is in landscape mode:

[image]

It doesn't matter if I turn the device when the popup is already visible or if I pop it up after the device is turned.  This is the code that I am using to display the popup.

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}

@IBAction func showPopUpDate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let popoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DateTimeSelectorView") as! DateVC

    popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    popoverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 350, height: 350)
    popoverVC.labelTag = sender.tag

    if sender.tag == 0 {
        popoverVC.showType = .date
        popoverVC.passedDate = date
    }
    else {
        popoverVC.showType = .time
        popoverVC.passedDate = time
    }

    if let popoverController = popoverVC.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .any
        popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        popoverController.delegate = self
        popoverController.sourceView = sender
        popoverVC.delegate = self

        present(popoverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How can I set this up so that the popover continues to look like it does in portrait mode?

Answer (score 0):

Please add **vertically center** and **horizontally center** **constrain** to the view.

Comment: Please elaborate.  I am not sure what you are asking me to do.  This is all done through storyboards.  I have the date control centered in the view.  The changing of the popover when in landscape seems like some kind of behavior of the system that I need to override.